# How to get entity that killed player bukkit?

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I am trying to make custom death messages when you get killed in certain ways. I want separate messages for when you get blown up by TNT or get blown up by a creeper. I tried debugging it and spawning a creeper and TNT and in the console it outputs the `e.getEntity().getKiller()` as `null` in the console. If I do `e.getEntity().getKiller().getName()`, it gives out an error.

here is my code for the debugger:

```
package me.Pale_Gray.BetterDeathMessages.deathmessages;

import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.entity.EntityDamageEvent.DamageCause;
import org.bukkit.event.entity.PlayerDeathEvent;

public class DeathByTnt implements Listener{

    @EventHandler
    public void onPlayerDeath(PlayerDeathEvent e) {
        String msg = e.getDeathMessage();
        System.out.println((Player) e.getEntity().getKiller());
        if (e.getEntity().getLastDamageCause().getCause().equals(DamageCause.ENTITY_EXPLOSION)) {
            msg = ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', "&cIt went off with a BANG!");
            e.setDeathMessage(msg);
        }
    }
    
}
```

I am only asking to focus in on the `System.out.println((Player) e.getEntity().getKiller());` because  I know the if statement isn't selective on entities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. There are `@Nullable` annotations on methods and javadocs so you know what method can be `null`.
2. `PlayerDeathEvent#getEntity#getKiller` method returns `Player` so you don't need to cast `Player` object to it.

   - Otherwise, this method only returns Player, if it killed by another living Player.
3. `Entity#getLastDamageCause` method can return null
4. `getCause()` method returns an enum so you don't need to use `equals`, you only need `==` for comparing enum values.
5. You could check some other `DamageCause` fields, including `ENTITY_EXPLOSION`. Sometimes when creeper explodes the damage cause can be `BLOCK_EXPLOSION`, maybe because too far away.